# Azure App Service Scaling powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have app service in my environment named "Standard" . Currently the app service is configured in standard tier small 1 instance.

Using powershell I am trying to scale the app service which will in turn scale the web apps inside this app service.
I want to change size to Medium and instances to 2.

Here is my snippet.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRMAppServicePlan -Name Standard -ResourceGroupName
 MyWebAppRG  -    NumberofWorkers 2 -WorkerSize Medium
```

When I run this command I am getting following error

```
Set-AzureRMAppServicePlan : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication, Version=0.11.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:11 char:1
+ Set-AzureRMAppServicePlan -Name Standard -ResourceGroupName MyWebAppRG  -Numbero ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureRMAppServicePlan], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.AppServicePlans.SetAzureAppSe 
   rvicePlanCmdlet
```

I am not sure, what's wrong here?  and what exactly this error means.

For the information, I am able to run other powershell commands just fine,example set-AzureRMResource and others. so isn't an environment issue.

Any help appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of the Azure Powershell are you using? This was a known issue in Azure Powershell 1.0.0. If you are using that version, use the version below instead. Do post back if you still see issues.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v1.0.1-November2015